# MFMessageComposeViewController alloc returns nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my application, MFMailComposeViewController works fine but creating a new instance of  MFMessageComposeViewController fails.

Here is the code for both:

```
-( IBAction)sendSMS: (id)sender
{
 MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
 picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

 NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject: cell.currentTitle ]; 

 picker.recipients = toRecipients;

 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

-( IBAction)sendEmail: (id)sender
{
 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

 NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject: email.currentTitle ]; 

 [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Its seemingly obvious that everything is linking correctly because the email view controller works fine. Is there something I am missing maybe configuration wise?

Comment: As the questioner commented on the accepted answer the MFMailComposeViewController results in `nil` is because he used the Simulator.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Have you checked `+[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]`?

From the  [MFMessageComposeViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html),

> Before presenting a message composition view, call the `canSendText` class method to ensure that the user’s device is appropriately configured. Do not attempt to present a message composition view if the canSendText method returns NO. If SMS delivery isn’t available, you can notify the user or simply disable the SMS features in your application.
>
> Starting in iOS 5, you can register to be notified of changes to the availability of text message sending by way of the `MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification` notification.

Reasons it might be returning `nil`:

- Device isn't running iOS 4.
- Device is an iPod Touch/iPad without iMessage enabled.
- No SIM card? (The view now shows in iOS 6; the app is not notified of the message send failure.)
- "Device" is actually the simulator. (Perhaps this works in iOS 6 too.)

Similarly, `[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]` returns `nil` when no mail accounts are enabled (you can quickly test this by disabling accounts in Settings), but also shows a "No mail accounts configured" alert for you. MFMessageComposeViewController does not do this.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I probably should have been more clear in that the issue arises using the simulator, which obviously doesn't have SMS capability.

Comment: If there is no SIM card, the app exits. why? it just gives a pop up message "no sim card present". it event send a SMS sent result to the delegate method. then exits. is there any way to prevent it from exiting?

Comment: Have you checked the console for messages? Does it crash or exit "normally"? Is there a crash log? Does attaching a debugger help?

Comment: `"Device" is actually the simulator.` yes please, can't stress to point this out enough.