# error on clicking the uiBarButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem, ibaction

[image]On clicking the uiBarButton,NSInvalidArgumentException occurs and my code is below:

```
-(IBAction) sendSms:(id)sender {

        MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

        picker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1234567890"];  
        picker.body = @"Help me";

        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] init];
    switch(result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Result: cancelled"];
            NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Result: sent"];
            NSLog(@"Result: sent");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Result: failed"];
            NSLog(@"Result: failed");
            break;
        default:
            message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Result: not sent"];
            NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
            break;
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message Status" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [message release];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

the errorr shows that nil modal view controller on target. Please tell me my error, i have linked the action of  that uibarButton properly with IBAaction in interface builder. Please help me asap. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste the output of the console here.

Comment: Only your console log might help us to crack your issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498531/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-alloc-returns-nil).

Your MFMessageComposeViewController object (picker) is not initialized properly.
The conditions that it would fail to initialize are listed there.