# MFMailComposeViewController not working iOS 9

Tags: xcode, email, object, null, ios9

I am using xcode 7.3 and using following code to open MfMailComposeViewController and object of mail composer goes nil after alloc init it.

```
- (void)openMailComposer {
NSString *emailTitle = @"Invite for SpotFit";

MFMailComposeViewController *mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mailVC setSubject:emailTitle];
[mailVC setMessageBody:AppLink isHTML:NO];

[self presentViewController:mailVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

}

Please provide any solution for it.
[image: screen shot for it]

Comment: Are you running on the simulator by any chance?

Comment: No i am running it on device. It is giving same error.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498531/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-alloc-returns-nil